Post-apocalyptic movie with food cans
I'm looking for a title of an movie I saw as a child (at least 25 years ago). 
The movie is probably produced in the '80s. It could be European, but I'm not sure about this. It could be a horror/thriller production for TV.
I don't remember much of it but this is what I still got in my mind:
A guy walks around, he seems to be the only guy left - mankind is killed by some strange disease. He is clueless about what happened.
On day he meets a young girl. Happy that he is not alone anymore, he invites her to have some food with him at the end of the day, realizing that she doesn't know how to open a can with a can opener.
Next morning she is also dead, but before she died, she opened all remaining cans of food - the guy is out of supplies now.
He is sad but his only comment is something like "At least you learned how to open them."
Hope someone can help.

Sounds like a typical twilight-zone twist.

That's true, but it wasn't TZ. Different style...

That's a striking story plot but it might help jog the collective SE memory if you could add any visuals you can remember - skin color, hair color, eye color, clothes, appearance, sets, anything.

Girl: ~10-14 years, longer, brunette or red hair. After she died, her face was a bit deformed. Guy: Thirties, smart, cultivated and dark short hair. Lot's of opened cans around a fireplace in the morning (probably more than they could have carried?!?). Undulating landscape. I can't remember more, sorry.

If not Twilight Zone, perhaps The Outer Limits?

As far as I know there where just two seasons of The Outer Limits produced within the sixties. This movie was produced within the eighties. Nevertheless I checked all plot summaries of all 49 Episodes but it didn't ring a bell. Sorry and thanks.

But what if people are just making up good scenes/film plots just to screw with us?

What would be the value of this? As far as I can tell, I got better things to do  than making up plots here...

The plot remind me of a book "Z for Zachariah" (Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_for_Zachariah ). It was adapted as a tv movie for the BBC Play of the day in 1984. There is also a recent remake: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_for_Zachariah_%28film%29

@user27221 I've had that same feeling! Some of these scenes are so great, it's hard to believe they're not easy to find!

@user3810626 I still have to check the recommendation of mattiav27. If this is not my movie, I will start a bounty regarding these "made up scenes". Beside that, I'm just describing one scene - the only one I can remember.

I apologize if that sounded like an accusation. I suspect what really goes on is, of the thousands of movies out there (some with only a handful of people who have watched all the way through), even the most forgettable will have one truly memorable scene or aspect. And that's what people comment on. There are five great (or at least memorable) minutes in some of the worst movies ever made, that people avoid like the plague.

Sure, no problem, and maybe it is a very bad movie - like I said, I don't remember the rest of it. Let's say may goal is to find out how great it really was. ;)But if we are starting to ask questions about great movies that everyone has seen and everyone can remember, we don't have to ask here... ;)  I'm mean, it is totally fair if this question won't get a final answer - it was just a try...

Sounds like something that could have happened in a Day of the Triffids version, though having read the book and seen the 1960's version, I don't remember this scene.

The Omega Man 
In 1975, biological warfare between China and Russia kills most of the world's population. U.S. Army Col. Robert Neville, M.D. is a scientist based in Los Angeles. As he begins to succumb to the plague himself, he injects himself with an experimental vaccine, rendering himself immune.wiki


Or mabye its https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Man_on_Earth

Most of the OP's question is about a very specific scene, though. Is it in this movie?

@Walt Yes there is the same girl and they eat food out of cans.

@Walt there is also a woman. And there is a can scene. It is about 3 years ago I saw this movie gem. I hope the op meant it.
